# Gatsby.js - Typography.js

Tags: typography, gatsby

since installing `typography.js` I get this error:

```
error There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

  14 |   // Create family + styles string
  15 |   var fontsStr = '';
> 16 |   if (props.typography.options.googleFonts) {
     | ^
  17 |     var fonts = props.typography.options.googleFonts.map(function (font) {
  18 |       var str = '';
  19 |       str += font.name.split(' ').join('+');

  WebpackError: Cannot read property 'googleFonts' of undefined

  - GoogleFont.js:16 GoogleFont
    ~/react-typography/dist/GoogleFont.js:16:1
...
```

Which I am not sure what it means or how to fix it.
I am using Gatsby.js default starter pack

`typography.js` as so:

```
import Typography from "typography";

const typography = new Typography({
  baseFontSize: "18px",
  baseLineHeight: 1.45,
  headerFontFamily: [
    "Avenir Next",
    "Helvetica Neue",
    "Segoe UI",
    "Helvetica",
    "Arial",
    "sans-serif",
  ],
  bodyFontFamily: ["Georgia", "serif"],
});
```

and the gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`, 
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: 'src/utilities/typography.js'
      },
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error and I was able to fix it by adding the export at the bottom like so:

```
export default typography;
```

Thanks to octalmage on the reactiflux discord for helping me with this. Works great now. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Alex! Works great. Really helpful. 
For others: As Alex suggested `export default typography` goes to the very bottom of the `typography.js` file.